# Creating a new column using existing columns, but in non-exclusive conditions

Tags: sql, schema, partition, group

This is for a case study.

I have the following table, **T1** with two columns: **c1, c2**

```
    C1     C2
    1       3
    5       2
    4       10
```

I want to create a table **T2** with both **C1, C2**, and a new column **C3** defined in a way that

```
 if C1 > 3  then C3 = "C1_big"
 if C2 > 3  then C3 = "C2_big"
 else C3 = "not_big"
```

so using our table **T1**, we get

```
    C1     C2     C3
    1       3     "not_big"
    5       2     "C1_big"
    4       10    "C1_big"
    4       10    "C2_big"
```

notice that the last row satisfies conditions for both "C1_big", and "C2_big", so we have two rows for that.

I was thinking of using CASE WHEN, but then it only applies to mutually exclusive events. For our case, "C1_big", "C2_big" can both happen for a row, so it doesn't need to be mutually exclusive.

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL query? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Presto/Trino this can be achieved using [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) and [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) (using succinct syntax here):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (c1, c2) as (
    values (1, 3),
        (5, 2),
        (4, 10)
)

-- query
select *
from dataset,
     unnest(
        if(
             c1 <= 3 and c2 <=3, array['not_big'],
             filter(array[if(c1 > 3, 'C1_big'), if(c2 > 3, 'C2_big')], x -> x is not null)
        )) as t(c3);
```

Without using Presto-specific functions - you can use `union all`:

```sql
-- query
select *, 'not_big' c3
from dataset
where c1 <= 3
  and c2 <= 3

union all

select *, 'C1_big' c3
from dataset
where c1 > 3

union all

select *, 'C2_big' c3
from dataset
where c2 > 3;
```

Comment: As far as time complexity goes, does the first one take less time and memory than 2nd one?

Comment: @user98235 in terms of time complexity they should be equal, in terms of the execution speed - depends on the SQL engine - if it can somehow find query similarity and optimize it then they should be similar, otherwise it will need to process the same data 3 times, hence it will be slower ~ 3 times (`explain analyze` confirms it in Trino)

Comment: thanks. (i thought of using presto, so this should work) one last question - why is "x -> x is not null" needed here? Not sure what this is for.

Comment: @user98235 check the linked docs and find `filter` function there - `x -> x is not null` is the second parameter: function accepting array element and returning bool.

Comment: oh, got it. thanks! I will read the linked doc.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169414/getting-the-max-date-per-each-key-per-user ? Thanks.

Comment: @user98235 - NP. Have tried to answer the question.